# Difference between packages libxml2-dev and libxml2

Tags: c++, linux-headers, libxml

I have simple C++ application that uses libxml2 library. For this purpose I need to install it. But which package I need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

System still complains regarding missing libxml header file.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Builds fine.

What is difference between libxml2 and libxml2-dev packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libxml2` contains the library itself, so to speak. `libxml2-dev` contains specifically the header files for C (or in this case, C++) development. This principle holds for many other packages as well. For example, `libmysqlclient21` contains the MySQL command line client library. If you want to use this library in your own code, you need to install the corresponding header files from the package `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: Link to https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/libxml2 will be useful.